# How to add an ActionListener to this class implementing JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

Hi there I have this class implementing a JTextField:

Which also should have an addActoinListener method, which I am not sure how to write...

```
package gui;

import gui.control.ExpressionListener;
import gui.control.NewListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public final class ExpressionView
    extends JTextField {

public String text;

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final ExpressionView instance = new ExpressionView();

private ExpressionView() {
    super("ExpressionView");

    // This is a singleton.
}

@Override
private void addActionListener {
    ExpressionView.addActionListener(ExpressionListener.instance);
}


}
```

The ExpressionListener class which kind of performs the action looks like this:

```
package gui.control;

import gui.ExpressionView;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;

import spreadsheet.Application;
import spreadsheet.Expression;
import spreadsheet.exception.NoSuchSpreadsheetException;
import ui.ExpressionInterpreter;
import ui.exception.IllegalStartOfExpression;
import ui.exception.InvalidExpression;
import ui.exception.InvalidPositionException;

public final class ExpressionListener
    implements ActionListener {

  public static final ExpressionListener instance = new ExpressionListener();

  private ExpressionListener() {
    // This is a singleton.
  }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(ExpressionView.instance.getText());
      Expression expression = ExpressionInterpreter.interpret(scanner);
      Application.instance.set(expression);
    } catch (InvalidPositionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchSpreadsheetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStartOfExpression e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidExpression e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }

}
```

So could you please help me and show me how to add this ActionListener to the ExpressionView class? :)

Comment: I can't resist to the fact to ask "why are you using singleton-pattern"? This pattern is way too often used in inappropriate situations and should be mainly avoided. It always removes flexibility and make evolution harder.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is enough:

```
ExpressionView.instance.addActionListener(ExpressionListener.instance);
```

Since they are both singleton classes why would you need a static `addActionListener` to `ExpressionView` class? You can already the one inherited from the `JTextField` on `ExpressionView` singleton instance.

Comment: Yeah ok but where exactly should this be, in the constructor? Or if not what is this? I do not recognize it as a method...

Comment: Since your singleton instances are static then you surely have some static code which uses them, there you can add the listener. Or directly in the constructor of one of them.

Comment: Can I ask you where you would put it (that line of code you gave me)?